# How to aggregate data by counting days in date?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have retrieved the following data from Athena:

```
book_id   cat_id   books    date       year   month  day
1          12        50   2020-05-08   2020   05     08
```

However, instead of books, I want to get the avg_books with the following formula:

```
SUM(books)/COUNT(DISTINCT(DAY([Date])
```

I am a beginner of SQL, so I could not do that. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

How about counting the dates?

```
select sum(books) / count(distinct date)
```

Or if you prefer:

```
select sum(books) / count(distinct year * 10000 + month * 100 + day)
```

Of course, you *could* use:

```
    select sum(books) / count(distinct extract(day from date))
```

But that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks. Well, when I query like this: ```SELECT book_id, month, year, sum(pk_offers_on_oop) / count(distinct date)``` I get the accurate result on monthly basis. But when I select date instead of month, year, it does not give me the correct result. I want to see the avg_books on a daily basis as well.